# No me deja crear Persistence

Tags: maven

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No me detecta el persistence no se por que. Alguno se le ocurre alguna idea?

Comment: Hola Xeanort99. Recuerda leer [ask] para mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. ¿Has depurado el codigo para ver que puede estar sucediendo?  Por favor, pon el codigo en formato de texto para que sera más legible, tarde menos en cargar la pregunta para los visitantes de la version movil y por si alguno tiene capadas las imagenes en su escuela/trabajo. Un saludo

Comment: Y esto no tiene nada que ver con Maven...